# hot from = excited from?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*How I escaped my certain fate by Stewart Lee*

> When Richard Thomas’s songs were arranged and underscored by
>   professional, commercial musical theatre arrangers, **hot from** Mamma
>   Mia! and such like, they necessarily made interpretive choices about
>   [...]

Does the author mean that these arrangers were **excited** about Mamma Mia! musical?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It means these arrangers were considered "hot" within their profession having very recently been involved with the (successful) *Mamma Mia!* musical.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense

Comment: As in *Covid-19 vaccination is a **hot** topic*, meaning *something **new** [that many people are interested in]*. Not the same as the even more metaphorical *Covid-19 vaccination is a **hot potato***, meaning it's a *such a **controversial / sensitive issue** that it's risky [especially for politicians] to express an opinion about it*.